# Автоматическая авторизация на сайте для пользователей Active Directory

Tags: авторизация, веб-программирование, active-directory

При входе в домен пользователь набирает логин и пароль. При открытии браузера пользователь набирает логин и пароль тот же самый для прокси. При заходе на корпоративный сайт, пользователь опять должен набирать тот же логин и пароль.

Хочется облегчить жизнь пользователю и авторизовывать автоматически на сайте, но сайт же получается об браузера должен получить какиенибудь идентификационные данные..

Или раз пользователь авторизовался на проксе, то при прохождении http запроса через прокси на этот корпоративный сайт, прокся добавляет в заголовки логин пользователя, которому нужно верить. Но в этом случае левый человек тоже может добавить самостоятельно такой заголовок.

Самостоятельно так и не смог понять как это делается. Решение этого вопроса в Интернете так и не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд отлично и свежо описано здесь
http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/216/windows-authentication-with-asp-net-web-pages

При условии, что у вас asp.net сайт )

Answer (score 0):

У меня черный пояс по Гуглению )))

http://dokuwiki.ru/auth/ad

Сам не пробовал.

Comment: Немножко не то. Проблем в авторизацией в AD у меня нет - все прекрасно работает. Я просто хочу сделать автоматическую авторизацию. Т.е. чтобы пользователю не нужно было вводить логин и пароль, чтоб он автоматически брался с его компа. Например в SharePoint - там  даже при первом входе пользователю не нужно вводить пароль, если в настройках сервера указана авторизация пользователей с домена.